# EntityFramework and EntityFramework Core Handling Update Command Plus Self Column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have case like this :

```
UPDATE TABLE_ABC
SET NAME = NAME + 'XXX_AA'
```

how can handle that without looping C# Without SqlRaw in EntityFramework or EF Core.
I need Pure Sintax Linq or Lambda and EF / EFCore.
Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to run raw SQL command (why not? it's MUCH faster) and want use EF - you should read entities from DB to memory (Select/Load), process them in memory (for/foreach) and save back to DB:

```
var entities = await dbContext.myEntity.ToListAsync();
foreach(var enitity in entities) {
  entity.Name += "AAA";
}
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is MUCH slower.

For EF 6, you may try [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) and build UPDATE command using it.

Comment: _why not?_: Because it's not always straightworward to do it. Hardcoding the query is not always an option because sometimes the DB table names can change. Then you need to map entity names to table names, which is possible, but a hassle. And then your DBA might map it to a (read-only) view and the query runs into an error. If you really want to run it on the DB, you should use stored procedures.